# Were there clones and/or national variants of IBM's 84-key AT keyboard?

Tags: ibm-pc, keyboards

The 84-Key IBM AT keyboard (the one with a visibly separated numbers block but without dedicated cursor keys, with ESC and a dedicated SysRq key in the numbers block) seems to be the rarest of the old IBM PC keyboard styles today, probably because it was replaced by the 102-key "MFII" keyboar rather quickly. I wonder - was it ever cloned? And did non-US national variants of this keyboard exist?

Answer (score 8):

The [IBM AT Technical Reference Manual](https://www.minuszerodegrees.net/manuals/IBM_5170_Technical_Reference_1502243_MAR84.pdf) of 1984 lists a few variants (p. 4-16):

[image]

The company I worked in then certainly had the UK keyboard, with the pound sign on the 3 and the hash symbol to the right:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is rare indeed, and international versions are probably even rarer.

There are non-US variants, one example is the French version, see https://www.jeuxvideovintage.com/index.php?title=IBM_PC_AT_84_key_Model_F_AZERTY_keyboard_%28clavier_IBM_mod%C3%A8le_F_Azerty%29

I seem to remember that also German and Swiss versions existed, but I don't have a reference for this.

Answer (score 1):

The question mentions “clones” of the [84-key IBM AT keyboard](https://www.minuszerodegrees.net/keyboard/IBM%20PC%20family%20-%2084-key%20keyboard.jpg).

One such “clone”, or near-clone, was the [85-key keyboard designed by Amstrad](https://www.seasip.info/AmstradXT/pc1512kbd.html) for their line of PC compatibles — such as the popular [Amstrad PC1512 / PC1640](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC1512) models.

This, of course, depends on how you define a “clone”. The keyboard in question is clearly inspired by the original 84-key IBM design but used an [incompatible keyboard interface](https://www.lo-tech.co.uk/wiki/Amstrad_Keyboard_Interface) in order to avoid patent issues with IBM. Amstrad’s keyboard design also adds, as a special feature, a digital, Atari-style joystick port, which produces special scancodes... the connector is on the back side of the keyboard and can be seen in the [photos on this page](http://www.timonradiosivut.fi/Amstrad_PC1640_SD.html).

According to the [technical reference manual](https://www.seasip.info/AmstradXT/1512tech/appendices.html#10), the 85-key Amstrad PC keyboard was available in the **US**, **UK**, **French**, **German**, **Spanish**, **Italian**, **Swedish/Finnish**, and **Danish** national layouts. I have personally used units which had the Swedish/Finnish layout.

(The PC1512 / PC1640 was an interesting PC clone in that it featured many custom solutions which did not quite become mainstream... such as a [4xAA battery compartment](http://www.timonradiosivut.fi/S811_13.jpg) for the RTC and BIOS settings, the afore-mentioned [digital joystick port](http://www.timonradiosivut.fi/S811_23.jpg) integrated to the keyboard, [a custom mouse and a custom mouse interface](https://www.seasip.info/AmstradXT/1512tech/section1.html#1.16.1), and [a colorful set of system floppies](https://www.dosdays.co.uk/computers/Amstrad%20PC1000/software/download.php) containing the [Digital Research GEM desktop environment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q53O3379TvA) and GUI-based [Locomotive BASIC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EH0BGEVYNYk), etc. Also, [the system PSU was integrated to the monitor](https://ctrl-alt-rees.com/2018-09-10-amstrad-pc1512-building-an-external-power-supply.html). See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PYpMXseflM) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WJUpNgOx_c) for more information.)